# R - Recode interval times as actual, mean and alternative variable value

Tags: r, databricks

Context.

The last interval per group (pid, medname, date) in interval_hrs variable will always == 24, as there is no way to calculate the interval.

I am attempting to code the following:

1/. If there is only one row per group (pid, medname, date), then the interval_hrs == 24.  When this happens, the value from the freqcount column will be used in the new_vars variable (highlighted by * in the desired output).

2/. If there is more than one row for the group, then I want to use the average value of interval_hrs for rows in the group instead of where the interval_hrs == 24 (last interval of each group) (highlighted by (mean) in the desired output).

3/. For the remaining rows I want to use the actual interval_hrs value for rows where interval_hrs is not equal to 24.

4/. I want the new values to be recorded in the new_vars column.

Dummy dataset.

```
        pid         medname         date                freqcount   interval_hrs                
        <chr>       <chr>           <dttm>                   <int>          <dbl>                              
 1      A           Drug1           2022-01-01 04:00:00         9           8                     
 2      A           Drug1           2022-01-01 12:00:00         1           3                    
 3      A           Drug1           2022-01-01 17:00:00         4           24                    
 4      A           Drug1           2022-01-02 19:00:00         9           24                    
 5      A           Drug2           2022-01-01 09:00:00         1           24                    
 6      A           Drug2           2022-01-02 13:00:00         7           1                     
 7      A           Drug2           2022-01-02 11:00:00         8           7                    
 8      A           Drug2           2022-01-02 18:00:00         3           24                   
 9      B           Drug1           2022-01-01 10:00:00         2           2                     
10      B           Drug1           2022-01-01 12:00:00         6           24                    
11      B           Drug1           2022-01-02 14:00:00         7           7                     
12      B           Drug1           2022-01-02 21:00:00         2           24
```

Desired output

```
        pid         medname     date                freqcount   interval_hrs new_var
        <chr>       <chr>       <dttm>                  <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>
 1      A           Drug1       2022-01-01 04:00:00       9         8           8   
 2      A           Drug1       2022-01-01 12:00:00       1         3           3   
 3      A           Drug1       2022-01-01 17:00:00       4         24       5.5 (mean=(8+3)/2)    
 4      A           Drug1       2022-01-02 19:00:00       9         24          9*   
 5      A           Drug2       2022-01-01 09:00:00       1         24          1*   
 6      A           Drug2       2022-01-02 10:00:00       7         1           1   
 7      A           Drug2       2022-01-02 11:00:00       8         7           7   
 8      A           Drug2       2022-01-02 18:00:00       3         24        4 (mean=(7+1)/2)   
 9      B           Drug1       2022-01-01 10:00:00       2         2           2   
10      B           Drug1       2022-01-01 12:00:00       6         24        2 (mean=(2/1)   
11      B           Drug1       2022-01-02 14:00:00       7         7           7   
12      B           Drug1       2022-01-02 21:00:00       2         24        7 (mean=(7/1))
```

The code I have tried.

```
df1 <- df %>% group_by(pid, medname, as.date(date)) %>%
mutate(new_var = ifelse(interval_hrs == 24, mean(interval_hrs, na.rm = TRUE), interval_hrs)) %>%
ungroup() %>% mutate(new_var = round(new_var, 2))

head(df1, 10)
```

This code returns a new_var with the same values as in interval_hrs.

Comment: The dates you have posted here are datetimes, so there's always one row per group. Try adding `mutate(date <- as.Date(date))`, or `group_by(pid, medname, as.Date(date))`.

Comment: Thank you, I have added the as.date to the date variable as suggested which excludes the time component. I am getting unexplainable results for Point 2/. in my question; for the mean I am getting 8 when I expect 6, such that ((4 rows of 6)/4 = 6).  Also, for single rows that ==24 in the interval_hrs column, it remains 24 and not the freqcount value as per my Point 1/. above.